# Junit with Spring - TestContextManager [ERROR] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, junit, integration-testing

In my Spring-Maven--Hibernate-Mysql runnint on Tomcat web app I'm running 2 types of Junit integration tests using 2 different Junit categories:

1. LocalTests - running in process (no server required), directly invoking my web layer methods(jersey in this case).
2. HttpTests - Simulating a client and calling my web-layer via an http request, requires tomcat up and running.

Above each test class I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:testApplicationContext.xml" })
```

And my test suite looks like that (this is one of 2, I have one for each category):

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(HttpTest.class)
@SuiteClasses({ ...All My Test Classes... })
public class HttpSuiteITCase {

    // Excluded: NotificationTests, ImageHttpTests

    /**
     * Run once before any of the test methods.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setTestsConfigurations() {
    TestConfiguration.setup(false);
    }
```

My testApplicationContext is actually empty, it only contains the component scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.app" />
```

As I run my local tests it everything works smoothly, but as I'm invoking mt HTTP tests it crashes:

```
2012-07-22 17:56:13 DefaultListableBeanFactory [INFO] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2598a35d: defining beans [httpBrandManagerTestsProxy,httpClubTestsProxy,<HERE THERE'S A BUNCH OF SPRING BEANS>,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,contextApplicationContextProvider,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2012-07-22 17:56:13 TestContextManager [ERROR] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@29565e9d] to prepare test instance [integrationTests.http.tests.UserLoginDataHttpTests@480d41f3]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
```

I tried tons of stuff nothing works :(
My testApplicationContext is under the test/resources folder.

I have noticed that the exception marks a specific class: UserLoginDataHttpTests.
But I can't see anything special about this class, just a regular spring bean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't your stack trace missing few "*Caused by*"s?

Comment: All the following "Caused by's" says: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException along with my spring beans. Its not so informative as far as I can tell..  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Without looking at it I can say that the last `Caused by` message described *precisely* what the issue is. Can you post the full stack trace (you can edit your question)?

Comment: Tomasz - you are right, I had to dig deep in the stack trace but eventually the solution was there, at the end of a very long long "caused by" block. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs since **Spring context** gets loaded before one of my listeners, which is defined in `web.xml`. **Spring** is initializing some beans that uses non-spring classes that gets initialized using my own listener. To solve the issue I should make sure my listener runs first.

Comment: How do you make listener runs first

Comment: @muthu It has been a while since this one and I'm sorry to say that I don't really remember what I did back than. Moreover, I'm really upset with this laconic answer (of mine), terribly sorry :(

Comment: @forhas I have met the same problem just now,Your answer inspired me.
I had extract super class of my test Classes,it extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests , but  RunWith and ContextConfiguration annotations only annotated on derived classes. When added these annotations, Tests passed. -

Comment: @forhas Laconic answer would be short but explanatory :)

Answer (score 3):

For me adding in VM Options **worked**.

Added this to VM Options for that test case: -Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above mentioned answer. You should also look for "caused by" to see if there is any dependency resolution problem. For example, if your class under test is MyService.java and it uses a dependency MyRepository.java. Then you should make sure all such dependencies are either Mocked or Autowired in your test class.

Answer (score 0):

Super late, but I just got this error.  In my case I'd updated a number of dependencies.  For me the solution was to do a Maven -> Update Project in eclipse.

Comment: did not work for me. tried to update Project also did a mvn clean install -U. That too did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database dependency make sure to provide related details in application.properties file.